# How to get power usage on a Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to get the power usage (in watts) but I can't figure out how. I looked at pmset and IOKit but couldn't find anything about it. [coconutBattery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) can calculate it for laptops using the *MacOS internal power information*.

Comment: iStat Menus also shows detailed data for this, so it must be available somehow.

Comment: Do you need this for both desktops and laptops, or just laptops?

Comment: Preferably both. Laptops would be a good start. @eiko: iStat Menus has sensors for CPU but I just found out that the full version of Hardware Monitor can calculate the total voltage and current which would allow me to calculate the power usage.

Comment: iStat shows power consumptions for most components, and for the power supply. Hardware Monitor looks good, too. (I just happen to have the other one installed)

Comment: @Eiko Hmm, not on my Mac. Maybe it's only available on newer Macs. (I got an iMac G5)

Answer (score 8):

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep Wattage
```

The utility also accepts an `-xml` flag; the specific key in the XML is `sppower_ac_charger_watts`.

Comment: On what kind of Mac did you run this? Mine doesn't have anything like that in SPPowerDataType.

Comment: Two different MBP Core 2 Duos. With more testing, looks like it's only available when the AC adapter is plugged in.

Comment: Maybe it's only available on laptops... I got it on a PowerBook G4 but not on my iMac G5.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -iE '(Volt|Amp)'` You can calculate the wattage by converting it from mV and mA.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this information for a laptop, call [IOPMCopyBatteryInfo](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOPMLib_h/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/IOPMCopyBatteryInfo) and look at the values for the kIOBatteryVoltageKey and kIOBatteryAmperageKey keys to compute the power usage.

Answer (score 2):

You should use  `ioreg -n "AppleSmartBatteryManager" -r -l` and from there it should be easy to calculate.

Comment: `ioreg -n AppleSmartBatteryManager -r -l | grep -iE '(Amp|Watt|Volt)'`
You can calculate the wattage by converting it from mV and mA.